# Angular 11 - Can't bind to boundary since it isn't a known property of div

Tags: angular, sticky

Anyone know what is this syntax called ?

```
<div stickyThing [spacer]="spacer" [boundary]="boundary" [enable]="true">
```

It is defining div as stickyThing, and I assume that this will add a property called spacer and boundary into the div. But I am getting 'can't bind to boundary since it isn't a known property of div'

I am using angular11, anything that I did wrong?
or is there a new syntax on using this stickyThing in a div?

https://github.com/w11k/angular-sticky-things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `AngularStickyThingsModule` module in your app mdule:

```
imports: [
    AngularStickyThingsModule,
],
```

Comment: I found out the issue, it was due to importing into the wrong module earlier. Thanks for answering!